# Проблема с удалением сообщения после его добавления

Tags: ajax, javascript, dom

Суть вот в чем: нужно сделать что-то похожее не стену ВК. По ходу, возникла следующая проблема. После того как пользователь ввел текст сообщения и нажал "отправить", отправляется `ajax` запрос, после успешного выполнения, опять же аяксом, это сообщение подгружается и встраивается в `DOM`. Там же, есть ссылка на удаление сообщения. Так вот, те сообщения, которые были добавлены непосредственно сейчас, не перезагружая страницу, удалить не удается. Удаляются лишь те, что были загружены в момент загрузки страницы. Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копать. Если нужен код, выложу сюда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите какая получается ситуация: при загрузке страницы вы навешиваете на существуещие объекты DOM необходимые действия. Но после подгрузки вы просто добавляете объекты в DOM, а скрипты-то не знают, что вы что-то меняли! Таким образом при добавлении новых элементов нужно вручную навешивать на них события - вот и всё. Сталкивался с этим лично, поэтому знаю о чём говорю.

Comment: Да. Спасибо. Я до этого давно дошел. Может подскажите каким образом в js event'ы навешиваются?

Comment: Я навешивал их сразу же после добавления элементов DOM, писал функцию и вызывал её после добавления. Т.е. в ajax() было примерно следующее:  

    success: function(data){
        $("#someDiv").append(data);
        initActions();
    }
    //Сама функция:
    function initActions(){
        $(".close").click(function(){...});
    }  
В принципе то же, что и советовал Вам @SilverIce

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, у вас стоит назначение события при нажатии на удалении где-то один раз. Ну что-то вроде `$('.comments .delbutton').click(...`

А когда вкидываете доб. объект, то в нем есть нужная структура, но ЕВЕНТ не развешен.
То есть после .append'a нужно доназначить событие (http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) или, что возможно проще, дописать банальный `< onClick="" >`

Answer (score 2):

Если используется JQuery то логично было бы применять live функцию
**http://api.jquery.com/live/**
PS:лично я, когда работаю без JQuery описываю функцию чтото типа bindDelete и т.д. в которой, например - в цикле вешаю onclick или еще какие-то события, собственно не суть какие, суть в том что написав ее не в просто в цикле а с проверкой существования привязки того или иного события к элементу, то можно потом просто вызывать эту функцию при добавлении.

PPS: почему на сайте нет проверки на пустоту при добавлении сообщения?О_о

Answer (score 1):

Странно, реал-тайм, как обновляются записи? Делайте - удаляйте объекты из DOM. После удаления - отдельный запрос на удаление из базы.

Comment: Да, так и делаю. Только ссылка которая js-ом добавляется вообще никак не реагирует на событие клика

Comment: Как так не реагирует?
Вы как добавляется в DOM новый комментарий?

Comment: Новое сообщение добавляется в DOM динамически. Именно оно и не удаляется. Остальные, которые со страницей загрузились, удаляются исправно.

Comment: Я понял - скиньте код, как вы добавляете в дом.

Comment: обрабатываю событие delLink.click();

внутри него если всё ок, то

container.prepend(data);
data - html код нового сообщения.
container - блок, куда вставляются масеги: var container = $("#messaages");

Вообще я решил проблему тем, что просто в html прописал onclick. Но я всё же хочу разобраться с тем, как удалять динамически добавленные элементы и тем способом, которым я не сумел

Comment: Коллега @SilverIce, в этом вопросе прав.